# WKB method to calculate the ground eigenvalue of a Quartic Potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, computational-physics, semiclassical

I've come across a problem while studying the WKB method. I want to calculate the eigenvalues of a symmetric quartic double well potential. It could be any potential. I chose it to be $$V(x) = x^4 - 4x^2 +4$$ 
The hamiltonian with $\hbar$ = $m$ = $1$ gives $$H = -\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2}{dx^2} + V(x)$$
and I plan to find the eigenvalues of the bound states given by the potential $V(x)$ represented bellow

[$\hskip1.7in$ [image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ke3BMm.png)

with returning points $x_2 > x_1$ and roots $x=\pm \sqrt{2}$

The **quatization*** problem for the **double potential well** with respect to **even** (**odd**) solutions is, for $x>0$ $$\theta \simeq (n + \frac{1}{2}) \pi \mp \frac{1}{2} e^{- \phi} \tag{1}$$

with $$\theta = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} p(x') dx'$$ $$\phi = \int_{0}^{x_1} |p(x')| dx'$$ $$p(x) = \sqrt{2m(E_n - V(x))} = \sqrt{2m(E_n - (x^4 - 4x^2 + 4))}$$

( *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics by David J. Griffiths, problem $8.15$ )

**My problem lies exactly in solving eq. ($1$)**, since it involves integrals of the square-root of a quartic function $$\int_a^b \sqrt{2m(E_n - (x^4 - 4x^2 + 4))} dx$$

I used *Mathematica* but it couldn't compute a solution.

Is there any approximation or trick I could use to solve it analytically? If not, any software that could do the computation?

PS: After solving numerically the $Schr\ddot{o}dinger$ equation for the ground state eigenvalue I obtained $E_0 \simeq 1.8$ with $\hbar$ = $m$ = $1$ as stated above. With the WKB method I'm hoping to obtain a similar result.

Comment: Why can’t you use numerical integration?

Comment: Because E_n is an unknown. The main goal of eq. (1) is to get an expressions for E_n. At least for the ground eigenvalue E_0, I would consider a battle won.

Comment: You integrate for various $E_n$ until you find one that works. There are systematic techniques for narrowing in on the right choice, similar to when you try to find the root of a polynomial numerically,

Comment: I get $E_0=1.74646$.

Comment: Look it up in Gradshtein&Ryzhik, though it is quite possible that such integrals are not solvable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in *Mathematica* using **NIntegrate** to do numerical integration and either **NSolve** or **FindRoot** to find the energy that satisfies equation (1).

In this way I found the $n=0$ energies $E_0^\text{even}\approx 1.74646$ and $E_0^\text{odd}\approx 2.07823$ with a few lines of code. For the former, $\theta\approx 1.43953$ and $\phi\approx 1.33739$; for the latter, $\theta\approx 1.73284$ and $\phi\approx 1.12677$. Since this is only an approximation, it seemed pointless to go beyond standard precision.

The next energies with $n=1$ appear to be "above the hump", where I don't think your equations apply, because they give nonsense.

Comment: Integrals of square roots of quartics are *Elliptic functions*.  There is probably an analytic solution to your integral if you look up a book about such functions.

Comment: I'm having trouble using NSolve / FindRoot. Could you tell what am I doing wrong? The Code:   **f[Ei_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  Sqrt[2 (Ei - (x^4 - 4 x^2 + 4))], {x, Sqrt[2 - Sqrt[Ei]], 
   Sqrt[2 + Sqrt[Ei]]}]**;                    g[Ei_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  Sqrt[2 ((x^4 - 4 x^2 + 4) - Ei)], {x, 0., Sqrt[2 - Sqrt[Ei]]}];        **FindRoot[f[x] - Pi/2 + Exp[-g[x]]/2 == 0, {x, 1.5}]**;

Comment: I cut and pasted your code into Mathematica, except for the final semicolon. The output for me is $\{x\to 1.74646\}$. If you really have a semicolon at the end you're not going to see this.

Comment: I just did it myself again, in a new notebook, and yes, worked out perfectly. Must have been some previous functions or variables that needed to be Clear[]. A rookie mistake as I am. Thanks G. Smith